# Flash RegExp Problem

Tags: flash

I am use RegExp. This code give sş. I want to make ss. How can I do this. Thanks for answers.

```
import RegExp.as;
var pattern:Array = new Array(); 
pattern[0] = new RegExp("ş","s"); 

var patternReplace:Array = ["s"]; 

function decomposeUnicode(str:String):String 
{ 
    str = "şş"
    for (var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++)
    { 
        str = str.replace(pattern[i], patternReplace[i]);
    } 
    return str; 
} 

trace(decomposeUnicode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is define the global flag "g" when creating you're RegExp. I don't know if you really want to define dotall (indicates if . matches new line characters) but that's what you're doing by setting "s" in the second parameter. I'll let it there for the example.

```
pattern[0] = new RegExp("ş","s","g");
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. How can I use this. for example str.replace(pattern[0]) ?

Comment: Th rest of your code did work, all you needed to do is set the global flag. Just add it to the params of the RegExp constructor when you set the value of pattern[0]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorthand version:

```
str = str.replace(/ş/g, "s");
```

Comment: Yes but I suppose he's creating an array and looping in it because he'll eventually want to process a bunch of replace. If that's not the case, your solution would be the way to go